# What are the big plugs for that you find on high demand devices in North America (120V-Areas)?

Tags: ac, fuses, device, socket

Talking about AMEA socket system and 120V.

High power demand devices like A/Cs do have bigger plugs with some switches on them.

What exactly is their purpose?

Seems like a fuse but isn't the socket cirquit fused against overload?

Comment: Can you show a picture of the "switches" you're talking about? Yes, high-current plugs are larger, and the pins are arranged so that they can't be confused with lower-current plugs. And yes, the branch circuit in the building that feeds the corresopnding socket is fused appropriately, but that doesn't mean that there's any reason to eliminate additional application-specific fuses in the equipment (or its plug).

Comment: I don't think I've noticed such plugs with switches or fuses. There are a few sizes used for electric stoves, 220V A/C units, electric dryers, kilns etc. and different ones generally used for industrial (twist-lock), but I've never seen a North American one with a switch.

Comment: Are these http://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=gfi+plug&tag=googhydr-20&index=aps&hvadid=34124356991&hvpos=1t1&hvexid=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=10301919369449148325&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=e&hvdev=c&ref=pd_sl_kujskuz9n_e the sort of plugs you're talking about?

Comment: Hi, YES. These [link](http://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=gfi+plug&tag=googhydr-20&index=aps&hvadid=34124356991&hvpos=1t1&hvexid=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=10301919369449148325&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=e&hvdev=c&ref=pd_sl_kujskuz9n_e) plugs are the ones I tried to describe.... (hard to find if you don't know the name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> High power demand devices like A/Cs do have bigger plugs with some switches on them.

It sounds like you are talking about the plugs with a built in [Ground Fault Interruptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual-current_device) designed to automatically disconnect the circuit if current flow from the "hot" line is diverted anywhere other than the "neutral".

It's not really the "high power" which suggests their presence, but rather the possibility of a current leakage path developing.

Comment: Maybe. Sounds probable to me. However there are usually no touchable metal parts. Despite... with split devices the outdoor part with the compressor may be vulnerable to creeping water -- should be IP65, though.

Comment: Actually This guess is RIGHT

Answer (score 1):

If you mean these types of plugs, they are to indicate what type of current the device needs/is rated for.

[image]

Image from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector#mediaviewer/File:NEMA_simplified_pins.svg)

Answer (score 0):

If this is  what you're talking about, It's called an "IEC power entry module" and it's fused internally and supplied with internal switches in order to switch between various mains voltages,

[image]

Comment: No, sorry. It is at the end (or beginning) of the cable. One compund with the pins.